# How does flink support local mode?

Tags: apache-flink

I would run my flink application in one machine, and I want to specify 20 cores for this application. Acutally, what I want to do, use spark as an example, is:

```
spark-submit --master local[20]
```

I would ask how I submit my flink application in one machine as spark does.

Comment: @MIkCode done, Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to set the number of [parallelism](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/parallel.html#client-level) as a  Cli command

> ./bin/flink run -p 10 ../examples/*WordCount-java*.jar